# Multi Availability Zone VIP in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, virtual-ip-address

I am trying to setup a VIP (virtual IP setup) - for a high availability HA setup for Redis with HA proxy, however to have a VIP for two HA instances in two different availability is proving to be difficult.

I was trying to follow this guide; https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316 here, however this uses the same availability zone to achieve VIP floating IP, and this wouldn't work for me as my different availability zones are in different subnets.

I have tried the above mentioned example with an Elastic IP; however it is not transferring between machines as expected with the script (http://media.amazonwebservices.com/articles/vip_monitor_files/vip_monitor.sh)

Please could someone guide me how to approach this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Leveraging Multiple IP Addresses for Virtual IP Address Fail-over in 6 Simple Steps](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316) article you reference is **over 3 years old**, so I wouldn't recommend this as a state-of-the-art method of doing failover.

The preferred method for HA is always to **load balance between servers** in multiple Availability Zones. Then, if one server or one AZ should fail, the other systems can take the full load of traffic (perhaps scaling-up to absorb the traffic).

For a requirement where only one server can be active at a time, **switching DNS names or Elastic IP addresses** would be recommended.

- **Option 1: Use [Route 53 Health Checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-simple-configs.html) to detect failure**, then route the DNS name to an alternate server (may involve waiting until TTL timeout for any cached DNS resolutions)
- **Option 2: Use a static Elastic IP address and reassign it to an alternate server**. This would involve some method to detect failure (eg the script in that article) and then an API request to associate the Elastic IP address to another server

Comment: Awesome, Thank you.

I have wrote a small script that does the Option 2, monitors the boxes for failure and automatically  reassigns the Elastic IP to the alternate server.